# 12 six-sided dice are thrown. What is the probability of getting each number twice?

Tags: probability, statistics

I got this: $\frac{6!12!}{6^{12}2!^6}$
but the answer is this: $\frac{{12!}}{6^{12}2!^6}$

Im not sure I understand why you wouldn't write the $6!$ because if the first die's value is #3 then you have 5 other values to get (after you roll the same again), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\frac{12!}{2!^6}$ anagrams of the string *112233445566* and $6^{12}$ possible outcomes.

What else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, but the dice don't have a number. There is no first one or sixth one.
That's why there isn't the 6!